# How to add Apache Beam direct runner to classpath?

Tags: java, maven, apache-beam

I am trying a simple spinoff of the MinimalWordCount example project for Apache Beam. I started a new project rather than downloading their archetpye. I'm running into an apparently common problem, that is not being solved by the common solution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Runner was specified and the DirectRunner was not found on the classpath.
Specify a runner by either:
    Explicitly specifying a runner by providing the 'runner' property
    Adding the DirectRunner to the classpath
    Calling 'PipelineOptions.setRunner(PipelineRunner)' directly
```

The common solution here on SO is to add the correct dependencies, which I have done. Here is my very simple POM:

```json
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_pipeline</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-direct-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.33.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So how do I add the direct runner to my classpath (or solve this issue in any other way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

from the `beam-runners-direct-java` dependency.